# undefined reference to `__floatundisf' when using hard float (PowerPC)

Tags: gcc, floating-point, powerpc

I'm building code for PowerPC with hard float and suddenly getting this issue.

I understand that this symbol belongs to gcc's soft-float library. What I don't understand is why it's trying to use that at all, despite my efforts to tell it to use hard float.

make flags:

```
CFLAGS += -mcpu=750 -mhard-float -ffast-math -fno-math-errno -fsingle-precision-constant -shared -fpic -fno-exceptions -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -mrelocatable -fno-builtin -G0 -O3 -I$(GCBASE) -Iinclude -Iinclude/gc -I$(BUILDDIR)
ASFLAGS += -I include -mbroadway -mregnames -mrelocatable --fatal-warnings
LDFLAGS += -nostdlib -mhard-float $(LINKSCRIPTS) -Wl,--nmagic -Wl,--just-symbols=$(GLOBALSYMS)
```

Code in question:

```c
static void checkTime() {
    u64 ticks = __OSGetSystemTime();
    //note timestamp here is seconds since 2000-01-01
    float secs = ticks / 81000000.0f; //everything says this should be 162m / 4,
        //but I only seem to get anything sensible with 162m / 2.
    int days  = secs / 86400.0f; //non-leap days
    int years = secs / 31556908.8f; //approximate average
    int yDay = days % 365;
    debugPrintf("Y %d D %d", years, yDay);
}
```

What more do I need to stop gcc trying to use soft float? Why has it suddenly decided to do that?

Comment: The issue seems to stem from the use of `u64`. If I convert it two two `u32` it works fine. Not sure if this is because gcc doesn't know how to do this, or if this CPU can't do it natively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Soft-float-library-routines.html), `__floatundisf` converts an unsigned long to a float. If we compile your code* with -O1 and run `objdump`, we can see that the `__floatundisf` indeed comes from dividing your u64 by a float:

```
    u64 ticks = __OSGetSystemTime();
  20:   48 00 00 01     bl      20 <checkTime+0x20> # Call __OSGetSystemTime
            20: R_PPC_PLTREL24  __OSGetSystemTime
    //note timestamp here is seconds since 2000-01-01
    float secs = ticks / 81000000.0f; //everything says this should be 162m / 4,
  24:   48 00 00 01     bl      24 <checkTime+0x24> # Call __floatundisf
            24: R_PPC_PLTREL24  __floatundisf
  28:   81 3e 00 00     lwz     r9,0(r30)
            2a: R_PPC_GOT16 .LC0
  2c:   c0 09 00 00     lfs     f0,0(r9)   # load the constant 1/81000000
  30:   ec 21 00 32     fmuls   f1,f1,f0   # do the multiplication ticks * 1/81000000
```

So you're getting it for a u64 / float calculation.

If you convert the u64 to a u32, I also see it going away.

Why is it generated? Looking at the manual for the [750CL](https://fail0verflow.com/media/files/ppc_750cl.pdf) which I'm hoping is largely equivalent to your chip, there's no instruction that will read an 8 byte integer from memory and convert it to a float. (It looks like there isn't one for directly converting a 32-bit integer to a float either: gcc instead inlines a confusing sequence of integer and float manipulation instructions.)

I don't know what the units for __OSGetSystemTime are, but if you can reduce it to a 32-bit integer by throwing away some lower bits, or by doing some tricks with common divisors, you could get rid of the call.

*: Lightly modified to compile on my system.